# Cannot Customize Bootstrap 4 (Beta) Variables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, node-sass, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

This is how I import style.css:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css?modified=1507947241"/>`

At the top of **style.scss** I have some non-Bootstrap code and the following:

`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`

I use **node-sass** with --output compressed. It compresses bootstrap and my custom CSS just fine. However, I simply cannot overwrite *any* bootstrap variable successfully. I want to change the primary blue to a darker blue:

```
$theme-colors: (
  primary: #003366,
)
```

And no variation of this declaration will do it. I've tried importing a custom _variables.scss, I've tried to declare anything before, after, in the middle of other lines. I've tried !important and everything I could find on Stack Overflow. :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 Beta 2 resolved this issue. [Read more here.](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/10/19/bootstrap-4-beta-2/) Simply upgrade and start customizing as you would expect to.

> We’ve improved the ability to customize Sass maps. With Beta 1, we
>   didn’t have a setup in place to modify your $theme-colors map without
>   replacing it wholesale. That’s been fixed in Beta 2—override existing
>   values and add more as needed.